# How to reload data into dataset after changes?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have written this code to update values of table `general_ledg`

```
con.Open()
cmd.Connection = con
cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("update general_ledg set party_name ='" + Party_nameTextBox.Text + "',party_add='" + Party_addTextBox.Text + "',party_dalali='" + Party_dalaliTextBox.Text + "' where party_id = '" + Party_idTextBox.Text + "'", con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Me.NxtradingDataSet.Clear()
Me.General_ledgTableAdapter1.GetData()
General_ledgTableAdapter1.Fill(NxtradingDataSet.general_ledg)

con.Close()
MsgBox("update successful")
```

Update is successful in database, but `DataSet` is not loaded with new values unless I close the form and reload it.

Comment: You should first stop using string concatenation to build your sql query. Instead use sql-parameters. On that way you prevent sql-injection.

Comment: I assume that `General_ledgTableAdapter1.GetData()` returns the complete `DataTable` from database. But you don't assign it to a variable so that statement is pointless.

Comment: yes it returns complete data table.how should it be done

Comment: You just need to call the code again; 
`Me.NxtradingDataSet.Clear()
Me.General_ledgTableAdapter1.GetData()
General_ledgTableAdapter1.Fill(NxtradingDataSet.general_ledg)`

Comment: its not working yet.patiently waiting for some expert help